# Loading another m-file to the workplace is not working

Tags: matlab, function, load

I want to load a particular m-file called myfile.m to my workplace.This matlab file contains several arrays which I need to load into my workspace.

--------------------------myfile.m----------------------------------

```
r_red=[218,2,1,12,238,106,246,14,26,77,244];
r_green=[65,61,37,247,151,217,229,235,218,2,1];
r_blue =[14,26,77,244,164,131,119,9,222,80,61,228];
```

---

In my work space I tried to run this code and some other supporting codes by using these arrays.The code I used is as follows.

```
addpath('D:\mydocs'); % This is the place where myfile.m is located.
load myfile.m;
```

When I run this I got the following error.
**Error using load
Unknown text on line number 2 of ASCII file D:\mydocs\keyfile.m
"r_red=[218".**

Any comments given with this regards is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: "mat" is for matrix, not mathematics. And mat files are binary data; you mean an m-file instead, ending in ".m". You `load` .mat files, and you `run` .m files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the initiative.But what I actually want is to have what ever the variables loaded to my workspace, so that I can use them.I tried changing load myfile.mat.But doesn't work even.For an example in php,by using the include command what ever the file included at the very beginning and their variables can be used further.I thought of  some thing like that.

Comment: Read and try my answer, and see what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `load` is for loading either binary data stored in `.mat` files, or text-based (ASCII) data files. What you have is a simple script in an m-file, ending in `.m`. You `load` `.mat` files, but you `run` m-files containing scripts:

```
run myfile.m;
```

From [`load` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html):

> load(filename) loads data from filename.
>
> > If filename is a MAT-file, then load(filename) loads variables in the MAT-File into the MATLAB® workspace.
> >
> > If filename is an ASCII file, then load(filename) creates a double-precision array containing data from the file.

Your file is *neither*.